# How to Deselect selected input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" id="first">
```

and have

```
 $('#first').select();
```

So, in some case I want to deselect the input, something like

```
$('#first').deselect();
```

Can you provide the code how to deselect selected input? But that is not **focus**, I am not talking about selecting input itself, but selecting the text in it. Like you double click on text. Thanks.

Comment: you mean `focus`?

Comment: No, I mean select not input itself, but select text

Comment: please try the reset value something like  $('#first').val(null)

Comment: Guys, not blur, because I am not focusing it, but selecting the text. Like double clicking the text. When you double click text in input, you select the text, thats what i mean. No not select tag but input.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nkbjvqwu/ ---- Blur is working fine....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange

Comment: `.blur()` should defocus from the input and only unselect the selected text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unselect what was selected in an input with .select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861312/unselect-what-was-selected-in-an-input-with-select)

Comment: Yes, blur is the correct answer, like in jsfiddle provided. But that's not working in my case. Okay, then I must search the bug in my code. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Based on jQuerys API documentation, [`.select()` is simply a helper function that performs focusing and selection of the text node](https://api.jquery.com/select/):

> In addition, the default select action on the field will be fired, so the entire text field will be selected.

So, if you want the opposite, calling `.blur()` will have the opposite effect. It will defocus from the field and also reset the selection. See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$('#select').on('click', function() {
  $('#first').select();
});

$('#deselect').on('click', function() {
  $('#first').blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="first" value="Lorem ipsum">
<button type="button" id="select">Select</button>
<button type="button" id="deselect">Deselect</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use two methods

```
input.blur();
input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd;
```

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

const select = ()=> {
  input.select();
}

const unSelect = ()=> {
  // Using blur()
  // input.blur();
  
  // or using this
   input.selectionStart = input.selectionEnd;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Select or unselect input value">
<button onclick="select()">Select Text</button>
<button onclick="unSelect()">UnSelect Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input').blur();
```